# Do live (versions of) unix distributions ever automatically pick up config info from a OS already installed on the machine?

Tags: security, boot, startup, live-usb

If I have, for example, an Ubuntu Live USB running on a machine with Ubuntu already installed, might the Live OS ever look for any kind of useful configuration info on the OS already installed on the hard drive without asking me first? Does any *nix live distribution have this kind of behavior?

Comment: I'm not aware of any that do, but so many exist that it's not unlikely that some do, especially some obscure ones.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: My experience with some versions of the Ubuntu installer is that they would offer to migrate e.g. your old Firefox settings into the new image. Granted, this is during installation, not in the running live image in which the installer was executing.

Comment: It wouldn't really make sense for them to do this, especially since you might be booting into a LiveCD due to improper system configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your first instinct would be correct. I've never heard of any Live  distro making use of configuration files that are already local to the system.

That being said you can of course install the Live distro into the local system, at which point it's now local to the system.